# how can check two variable in the condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.supplier').on('click', function(){
        var supplier = $('.supplier').is(":checked");
        var customer = $('.customer').is(":checked");

        // if both is unchecked, hide the table
        if( supplier && customer == false){
            alert('hide table');
        }
        // if supplier is checked, show supplier, else hide supplier
    });
```

I want to hide the table if i don't check the .suppler and .customer

Thanks you so much.

Comment: you have to check both condition use this `supplier == false && customer == false` instead of `supplier && customer == false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that hasn't really been addressed in the previous answers (great as they are) is that you're only calling your function when you click `.supplier`.  I'd imagine you want to call this function when you click on either `.supplier` or `.customer`.  If so, you'll need to add `.customer` to your selector:

```
$('.supplier, .customer').on('click', function(){
    var supplier = $('.supplier').is(":checked");
    var customer = $('.customer').is(":checked");

    // if both is unchecked, hide the table
    if( !supplier && !customer){
        alert('hide table');
    }
    // if supplier is checked, show supplier, else hide supplier
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I forgot to insert .customer :D

Answer (score 3):

Currently your if clause look like this:

```
if( supplier == true && customer == false){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

You need to compare the `supplier` with `false` as well, so you can use:

```
if( supplier == false && customer == false){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

or:

```
if( !supplier && !customer){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

instead of:

```
if( supplier && customer == false){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var supplier = $('.supplier').is(":checked");
```

in your above line `supplier` is boolean variable. So you can use it how you want to use.

```
   if( !supplier && !customer){
        alert('hide table');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
if (supplier == false && customer == false){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

or

```
if (!supplier && !customer){
    alert('hide table');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use betwise operator

```
if( supplier & customer == false){
    //alert
}
```